# Can I render multiple element in a ternary condition without else?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-statements

I have the following code that allows me to retrieve a user's personal link on several social networks:

```
<ul className="navbar-nav my-2 my-lg-0">
  {
    settings !== null &&
      <li className="nav-item">
        <a className="nav-link" href={settings.facebook.url}>Facebook</a>
      </li>
  }
  {
    settings !== null &&
      <li className="nav-item">
        <a className="nav-link" href={settings.twitter.url}>Articles</a>
      </li>
  }
</ul>
```

However, since the `settings` object is retrieved by an Ajax call to the database, this is asynchronous and I have to make sure that `settings exists before making it showing up some datas.

My question is, since the following doesn't work:

```
<ul className="navbar-nav my-2 my-lg-0">
  {
    settings !== null &&
      <li className="nav-item">
        <a className="nav-link" href={settings.facebook.url}>Facebook</a>
      </li>

      <li className="nav-item">
        <a className="nav-link" href={settings.twitter.url}>Articles</a>
      </li>
  }
</ul>
```

Is there any way to make one verification for multiple React elements?

Thank you in advance

Comment: `{settings && <React.Fragment><li>...</li><li>...</li></React.Fragment>}`

Comment: whether you use fragments or arrays or whatever, the important thing is to remember that for each jsx expression, you ultimately have to return one element.  That is why it would not work.  It then forced people to wrap these groupings in some trivial div just to get it to come out right.  Or, if using the array approach you needed to add keys that meant nothing as well.  This is why the `React.Fragment` element was created.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you can use an array to return multiple elements

```
<ul className="navbar-nav my-2 my-lg-0">
  {
    settings !== null ?
      [
         <li key={'anything_1'} className="nav-item">
           <a className="nav-link" href={settings.facebook.url}>Facebook</a>
         </li>,
         <li key={'anything_2'} className="nav-item">
           <a className="nav-link" href={settings.twitter.url}>Articles</a>
         </li>
      ]
      :
      null
  }
</ul>
```

Comment: Remember key for the li items when used in an array, e.g. `<li key="key1">`

Answer (score 7):

The elements returned if the condition passes need to be wrapped inside a single element, such as `<div>` or, as [@kunukn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/815507/kunukn) suggests `<React.Fragment>`

```
<ul>
  {
    setting !== null && (
      <React.Fragment>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <a className="nav-link" href={settings.facebook.url}>Facebook</a>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <a className="nav-link" href={settings.twitter.url}>Articles</a>
        </li>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll dig into React.Fragments, never heard of it but it might be really interesting!

Comment: I prefer this because there's not need for `key` specification.... also for cleaner syntax: `<> {items} </>`